# Vertx executeBlocking use event loop instead of worker thread

Tags: java, vert.x, event-loop

I came from programming ideology of one request = one thread and now I want to understand the concept of event loop using `Vertx`. According to docs if we use a blocking operation we should pass it to the `executeBlocking` method.

```
Verticles use the Vert.x worker pool for executing blocking actions, i.e. executeBlocking or worker verticle.
```

I have some questions related to this paragraph from `http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/groovy/`

This is my code:

```
public class JdbcVertx extends AbstractVerticle{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx v = Vertx.vertx();
        v.deployVerticle(new JdbcVertx(),new DeploymentOptions().setWorkerPoolSize(10));
        
       
    }
    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        JDBCClient client = JDBCClient.createNonShared(this.vertx, new JsonObject()
                                .put("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test")
                                .put("user", "postgres")
                                .put("password", "pw")
                                .put("driver_class", "org.postgresql.Driver")
                                .put("max_pool_size", 30));
                                
        this.vertx.createHttpServer()
                .requestHandler(r -> {
                    int i = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                    System.out.println("Req id: " + i+ " "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    client.getConnection(handler -> {
                        if (handler.failed()) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(handler.cause());
                        } else {
                            final SQLConnection connection = handler.result();
                            this.vertx.executeBlocking(blockingCodeHandler->{
                            connection.execute(execute(), hndlr -> {
                                connection.close(closehndlr -> {
                                    if (closehndlr.failed()) {
                                        throw new RuntimeException(closehndlr.cause());
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("CON end: "+i+" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                                        r.response().putHeader("content-type", "text/html").end("Response: " + i);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                            },false,as->{});
                        }
                    });
                }).listen(8080);
    }
    
    private String execute(){     
            return "insert into rubbish (name) values ('test')";
        
    }
```

I send 100 requests to http server this is output:

```
Req id: 45 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Req id: 22 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Req id: 96 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Req id: 85 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Req id: 33 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
CON end: 22 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
CON end: 33 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
CON end: 45 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
CON end: 85 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
```

1. How event loop switched between requests (from the output, it first gets some requests and then gives them responses)?

2)I use `executeBlocking` method but how you can see code above use only event loop thread named `vert.x-eventloop-thread-0`

3)According to first question vertx event loop switched between request but if i change method `execute` to:

```
 private String execute(){ 
        Thread.sleep(3000);
            return "insert into rubbish (name) values ('test')";      
    }
```

It will stop the event loop until time out is not finished

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

1) You can look at EventLoop this way: each time you provide a handler, it's another function that is put on a queue of sort.

When your first requests come in, it may look something like this

`requestHandler (R1)
requestHandler (R2)`

Then EventLoop wil
l pop first element in the queue, and put it's result back on the queue:

`requestHandler (R2)
getConnection (R1)`

Then third request may come in, while we popped `requestHandler (R2)`:

`getConnection (R1)
requestHandler (R3)
getConnection (R2)`

And that repeats, hence `Loop`

2) You don't do anything in your blocking handler, actually. Add some large loop before `if (closehndlr.failed()) {`, and you'll see warnings.

What happens now is that you're doing `async->sync->async`, and your sync is basically 0ms.

You can see this with the following code:

```
vertx.setPeriodic(1000, h -> {
        System.out.println("Periodic on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
       vertx.executeBlocking(f -> {
           System.out.println("Future on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
           f.complete();
       }, r -> {
           System.out.println("Result on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
       });
    });
```

Prints:

```
Periodic on vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Future on vert.x-worker-thread-3
Result on vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Periodic on vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Future on vert.x-worker-thread-4
Result on vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
```

3) Don't use `Thread.sleep(3000)` :) By doing that, you just ask the EventLoop to stop for 3s. You've also should have seen warning regarding that.

Comment: Thank for response, but what about executeBlocking, why vertx use eventloop inside executeBlocking code, from docs it should use thread from worker pool?

Comment: In short - it does run on worker thread, you just don't print it :) I also added code example to my 2nd answer to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 0):

Add param "false"

```
vertx.executeBlocking(f -> {
           System.out.println("Future on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
           f.complete();
       }, false ,r -> {
           System.out.println("Re enter code here`sult on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
       });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).